# Download file from shared gisk

Tags: android, kotlin, smb

Is there any way to downloads files from local network drive programmatically?
I need something like `val file = File("/z/folder/")` where 'z' — local network drive
**UPDATE**
Target protocol is SMBv1

Comment: What protocol is the local network drive using? For example, if this is Windows SMB/CIFS, look into something like [smbj](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj) or [jcifs-ng](https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng).

Comment: @CommonsWare yes it's Wndows SMB. Google [lib](https://github.com/google/samba-documents-provider) looks good. Thsnk you

Comment: @CommonsWare, sorry the task has changed, i need Smb1 protocol. These libs aren't supports it.